# How can select 1 element from the 8 elements matching my selectors. [Cypress test]

Tags: css, css-selectors, cypress, ui-automation

I am trying to verify the heading of a section when running a test, using this locater `[data-cy="offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer"] .flex span:first-child` 
I am getting 4 elements I want to select the first one**(Joined)** of the 4 elements

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. `eq(0)` will get the first `[data-cy="offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer"]` and then `within` will make sure that the `Joined` element only within the `[data-cy="offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer"]` is selected.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer"]')
  .eq(0)
  .within(() => {
    cy.contains('span', 'Joined').click()

    //Checking number as a string
    cy.contains('span', 'Joined').next().should('have.text', '1')

    //checking number as a number
    cy.contains('span', 'Joined')
      .next()
      .invoke('text')
      .then((num) => +num)
      .should('eq', 0 + 1)
  })
```

If you want to check them independently, you can do this:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer"]')
  .eq(0)
  .within(() => {
    cy.contains('span', 'Joined').click()

    //Checking number as a string
    cy.get('span[class*="flex"] span').eq(1).should('have.text', '1')

    //checking number as a number
    cy.get('span[class*="flex"] span')
      .eq(1)
      .invoke('text')
      .then((num) => +num)
      .should('eq', 0 + 1)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you again Alapan, this works but, this span contains 'Joined' & '1' which can be located using the same as you have suggested. While 'Joined' is fixed and won't change The number 1 is a sum of some elements. So to verify if the sum is accurate I want to locate it separately. Will that be possible?

Comment: As we know the second span will have the number, we can simply use `next` which will select the immediate next sibling, and then do the assertion. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer it works. Was wondering if there can be a direct approach to check '1'. Were we don't need to first check 'Joined'. Either ways you have been more then helpful as always :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    cy.get("[data-cy=offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer]>span")
    .eq(0)
    .should('contain', 'Joined')
    .click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `.eq()` in this instance can be not as readable when debugging if it were to fail.

[`.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains) is a powerful command that allows you search for the first element containing text with an optional selector.

For your use, it would be better to use the `data-cy` attribute with the text of the first header `Joined`.

```js
// returns the for 'Joined' header
// you can drill down to it's child elements
cy.contains("[data-cy=offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer]", 'Joined')
  .should('be.visible')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have the same locator for 4 elements so you can use text within these locators to get the unique element. Apart from already provided solutions, you can also use the below snippet

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer"]').contains('Joined')
```

and if you want to check if the next no is 1

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="offerBreakUpTableHeaderCellRenderer"]').contains('Joined').next().should('have.text', '1')
```

Here you have to replace the text that you are looking for and don't have to worry about the order of element